# Is TradingChart Broken?

Tags: finance, charts

I'm getting pinking on mouseover for this:

```
Style[TradingChart[{"IBM", DatePlus[-90]}, {"Volume",
   Style["MESASineWave", {White, Blue}], 
   Style["BollingerBands", White], 
   Style["DoubleExponentialMovingAverage", Yellow]},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: I copy and pasted your exact code into a notebook in M11.0.1 on Windows 10 and I do not see the issue. https://puu.sh/sNxR0/d5f82c01ea.png

Comment: I'm on macos, v10

Comment: Works for me on OSX 10.12.2 and MMA v11.0.1